# How to pass (multiple) regex parsed function parameters to a python function

Tags: python, eval

I'm trying to build a python class that parses a string and if it matches a regex that looks
like a function call attempt to call that function on the class, passing in any parameters.

For example a string like "foo("a", 20")" would translate to something like self.foo("a", 20).

Here is the code that I have so far..

```
class FooTranslate(object):
    def create_string(self, letter, size):
        return letter*size

    def run_function(self, func_str):
        match = re.match("([\w_]+)\((|[\W\d\w\,]+)\)", func_str)
        if match == None:
            print "Couldn't match a regex!"
            return False
        else:
            func, fargs = match.groups()

        try:
            if fargs == "":
                return self.__getattribute__(func)()
            else:
                return self.__getattribute__(func)(eval(fargs))
        except AttributeError, e:
            print "Invalid function call: %s" % (func)
            return False
```

This code works in the basic cases...

```
In [1018]: foot = FooTranslate()
In [1019]: foot.run_function("foo()")
Foo!
In [1020]: foot.run_function("bar(2)")
FooFoo
```

However in the case of using 2 argument functions:

```
In [1021]: foot.run_function("create_string('a', 2)")

in run_function(self, func_str)
     24                 return self.__getattribute__(func)()
     25             else:
---> 26                 return self.__getattribute__(func)(eval(fargs))
     27         except AttributeError, e:
     28             print "Invalid function call: %s" % (func)

TypeError: create_string() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

The reason why is that the eval() call returns fargs as a tuple, which create_string()
takes as only a single argument. Any idea how I can pass a variable number of arguments
through to a function call? Or have a better alternative way to do this?

Comment: Have a look at `ast.literal_eval()` as a safer alternative to eval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`*` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921847/python-once-and-for-all-what-does-the-star-operator-mean-in-python) to explode a tuple into separate arguments to a function. For example:

```
def f(a, b, c):
    print a, b, c
```

If I call `f(...)` like this:

```
f((1,2,3))
```

I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: f() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)
```

But if I call it like this:

```
f(*(1,2,3))
```

I get:

```
1 2 3
```

The `*` operator will even work if the function takes a variable number of arguments. For example, given the following function:

```
def f2(a, b, *args):
    print a, b,
    for x in args:
        print x,
    print
```

If I call `f2(*(1,2,3,4,5))` it prints:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: I suspect this is the answer I'm looking for, thanks! If anyone has better methods of doing this (i.e. not using eval), that would be very useful to.